# Filtering specific tags in groovy XMLslurper

Tags: xml, groovy

I have an xml-document, that I want to parse using the XMLslurper. This actually works quite fine, but I have problems when reading some tags, cause there can be multiple lines of it in the same node like:

```
<element name="ABC">
    <description>lorem ipsum</description>
    <description>foo</description>
    <description type="DETAILED">some text</description>
</element>
```

If I use `element.description.text()` now, I get `lorem ipsumfoosome text` as output. How do I have to code it, so that:

1. Only the first `description` tag is read
2. Only the (first) `description type="DETAILED"` tag is read
3. All tags are read but at least seperated by spaces

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you parse XML document with `XmlSlurper` you access `element` tag as a [`NodeChildren`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/util/slurpersupport/NodeChildren.html) which implements `Iterable` interface. That is why you can apply following operations:

1. To get the first description tag ([`Iterable.first()`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/lang/Iterable.html#first())) :

   ```
   element.description.first()?.text()
   ```
2. To get the first description tag with type `DETAILED` ([`Collection.find(Closure cl)`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/Collection.html#find(groovy.lang.Closure))):

   ```
   element.description.find { it.@type == 'DETAILED' }?.text()
   ```
3. To get all descriptions separated by space ([`Iterable.join(String separator)`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/lang/Iterable.html#join(java.lang.String))):

   ```
   element.description.join(' ')
   ```

Full example:

```groovy
def xml = '''
<element name="ABC">
    <description>lorem ipsum</description>
    <description>foo</description>
    <description type="DETAILED">some text</description>
</element>
'''

def element = new XmlSlurper().parseText(xml)

println element.description.first()?.text()
println element.description.find { it.@type == 'DETAILED' }?.text()
println element.description.join(' ')
```

Output:

```
lorem ipsum
some text
lorem ipsum foo some text
```